# I have created a PostgreSQL table but I can't SELECT if I use the WHERE parameter

Tags: postgresql, string-constant

I am really new at coding in general.

I have created a table but when I try to use `SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = "adminis");` I get `ERROR: column "adminis" does not exist`. What I am trying to do is to find the user 'adminis' and get the other columns. I have also gone to the documentation but it really does not say a lot.

The table in question:

```
 user_id | username |      email      | password
---------+----------+-----------------+-----------
       1 | adminis  | admin@admin.com | ********
```

Thank you

Comment: `WHERE (username = 'adminis' );` Strings are delimited by single quotes in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

*Double* quotes are used for delimiting *entity names* (if needed), for example:

```
select *
from "my silly table name with spaces"
```

*Single* quotes are used to delimit *text*. Using your case as an example:

```
select *
from users
where username = 'adminis'
```